# After the output, the text with the ncurses library does not disappear

Tags: c++, c++17

```
void grop_goblin_shord(int cols)
{
    int messagesTicks = (2 * TICKS_PER_SEC);
    int grop_goblin_shord1,
        grop_goblin_shord2;
    if (num_lvl < 10)
    {
        grop_goblin_shord1 = rand() % 2;
        grop_goblin_shord2 = rand() % 1;
        if (grop_goblin_shord1 == grop_goblin_shord2)
        {
            if (messagesTicks > 0)
            {
                mvprintw(0, 1, "You received the goblin sword");
                while (messagesTicks >= 0)
                {
                    messagesTicks--;
                }
            }
            else if (messagesTicks <= 0)
            {
                clear();
                refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to count through ticks, I indicated that `constexpr int TICKS_PER_SEC = 60;`
and in `int messagesTicks = (2 * TICKS_PER_SEC);`
and took away 1 from messagesTicks and when in the loop and when the text ended, it should have been cleared, well, something, it doesn’t disappear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Introduce 'usleep' after printing the message.Screen refresh before clearing

void grop_goblin_shord(int cols) { int messagesTicks = (2 * TICKS_PER_SEC); int grop_goblin_shord1, grop_goblin_shord2; if (num_lvl < 10) { grop_goblin_shord1 = rand() % 2; grop_goblin_shord2 = rand() % 1; if (grop_goblin_shord1 == grop_goblin_shord2) { if (messagesTicks > 0) { mvprintw(0, 1, "You received the goblin sword");usleep(1000000);sleep for 1 second clear(); refresh(); } } } }

Comment: This doesn’t work, I need it, without stopping the code